# .ajaxStart and .ajaxStop don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a loading gif that I want to display and hide before and after Ajax request using ajaxStart and ajaxStop. Nothing works:

HTML:

```
<div id="loading" style="display: none"><img src="loading.gif></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event)
{

    $.ajaxStart(function() {
    $( "#loading" ).show();
    });
    $.ajaxStop(function() {
    $( "#loading" ).hide();
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'models/fetchUsers.php',       //the script to call to get data
        data: $("#searchForm").serialize(), //add the data to the form
        dataType: 'json',                   //data format
        success: function(data)             //on recieve of reply
        {

            $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
                $('#itemContainer').append(value.user_id);
            });
        },
        error: function()
        {
            $('#itemContainer').html('<i class="icon-heart-broken"> <?= $lang["NO_DATA"] ?>');
        }
    });
```

Comment: it is not included in the script

Comment: You want to show the animation for this Ajax call or for *every* Ajax call?

Comment: do this in the success of the ajax ("#loading" ).hide(); and use $( "#loading" ).show(); before the ajax call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [ajaxStart](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [ajaxStop](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/)

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
      $( "#loading" ).show();
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
      $( "#loading" ).hide();
});
```

There is problem in your HTML also **("loading.gif")**

```
<div id="loading" style="display: none"><img src="loading.gif"></div>
```

Add `event.preventDefault();` in your submit function, that will prevent a submit button from submitting a form.

**Or** Other way is to do the things in your function only, without calling global functions of ajax.

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $( "#loading" ).show();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'models/fetchUsers.php',       //the script to call to get data
        data: $("#searchForm").serialize(), //add the data to the form
        dataType: 'json',                   //data format
        success: function(data)             //on recieve of reply
        {

            $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
                $('#itemContainer').append(value.user_id);
            });
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('#loading').hide();
        },
        error: function()
        {
            $('#itemContainer').html('<i class="icon-heart-broken"> <?= $lang["NO_DATA"] ?>');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The first part didn't work, I already mentionned it in my question, but the second did, thank you, so I will take this answer

Comment: @user2997418 Glad to see that it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
   $("#gif-image-id").show();

}).ajaxStop(function(){
   $("#gif-image-id").hide();
});
```

Put this as a separate event (**outside the submit event**), and change the selector to what ever the image id actually is.

Comment: it should. update your code so i can see what youve done